# django HttpResponseRedirect and ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES

Tags: django, url, reverse

I'm new to django (1.5.1) and got a bit stuk with HttpResponseRedirect.
If I understand right that needs a static string, and when you want it to dynamic redirect, you get a reverse() or a get_absolute_url() 
I think I get the part of the get_absolute_url, but I'm stuck on redirecting to the following url (first is mysite.urls.py  second is my characters.view.py

```
url(r'^users/', include('characters.urls')),
url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/characters/$', views.user_characters, name='user_characters'),
```

from this view:

```
if new_char_form.is_valid():
    #save form with commit=False
    new_char_obj = new_char_form.save(commit=False)
    #set user and save
    new_char_obj.user = user
    new_char_obj.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('%s/characters/' % user.id)
```

So I know I can't use the HttpResponseRedirect that way, and since I can't include a get_absolute_url function in the user model, I found the next option.

Include this in my settings

```
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
'auth.users': lambda o: "/users/%s/" % o.id,
}
```

but then I have no clue how to call for that.
Can someone please give me help (sort of stuck on this for some time)

With kind regards
Hans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to redirect to the `user_characters` view is to use the [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

# in the view
return redirect('user_characters', user.id)
```

This is equivalent to using [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) and [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse)

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# in the view
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_characters', args=[user.id]))
```

If you want to use [`ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#absolute-url-overrides) to override the `get_absolute_url` method for the `User` model, you have to make sure that the url matches the format of your view named `user_characters`.

```
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
    'auth.users': lambda o: "/users/%s/characters/" % o.id,
}
```

You would then be able to call `user.get_absolute_url()` in your views, and do

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(user.get_absolute_url())
```

Or, since the `redirect` shortcut allows you to pass a model instance:

```
return redirect(user)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It works, Got another short question for future related redirects. user_characters in what way does that refer to /users/(user_id)/characters.  i get that the user.id fills in the id.

Comment: `user_characters` refers to the url pattern with regex `r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/characters/$'` because you have named it: `name='user_characters'`. It's not completely DRY -- if you changed the URL pattern you would have to update the `ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES`. For bonus points, you could try to use `reverse` in `ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES` instead, to cut down on duplication.

Comment: Thanks, i shall try the ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES as well cause think that is the best in the end. (can make the redirecting alot easier when i have to redo it.